# I'm getting slow registration times on asterisk mysql reatime - how to speed up?

Tags: asterisk

I am getting very slow sip registration times (excess of > 10s) via mysql realtime. I have tried indexing, though this has made no difference.
I have indexed the secret and the username. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk realtime (ARA) work ok on multiple systems.

So more likly you have issue on sql side or extreamly bad setup.

You can get exact queries using mysql query log or using debug in asterisk.

Comment: with the query logs nothing is coming up for slow queries >1s that would cause this issue..

Comment: Just check every query execution time. Sorry, there are no way guess without real debug